# Can we read amplitude of an MP3 audio without decoding?

Tags: java, android, audio, graph, mp3

Actually, I need to draw a graph of amplitude for my app, but decoding takes too long time and I want to get rid of it. Could anybody show me a proper way to do that?

Comment: Why is decoding too slow?

Comment: Can you read a book without opening it?

Comment: I followed an instruction here https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample. But it takes my phone 30~1min to decode a mp3 audio. 

Yeah I know that's a dumb question but just looking for some hope

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I think it's a reasonable question.  An MP3 file is not just a simple representation of a waveform.  It's a much higher-level representation of what the signal sounds like to a human ear.  Unfortunately, I have not worked with that algorithm, so I don't know the answer, but it seems quite reasonable to ask whether one could extract just a low-res version of the amplitude envelope without doing all the work to fully reconstruct the original waveform.

Comment: @jameslarge Perhaps it sounds reasonable, but MP3 is a *lossy* compression algorithm of the waveform (you have to *decode* it to retrieve the waveform). My analogy may not be perfect, but it fits.

Comment: Yes, you have to decode it to retrieve the waveform, but you might not have to _fully_ decode it to retrieve the amplitude envelope.

Comment: Might I suggest running your code on a PC? An average consumer pc-cpu should be able to run much more complex instructions than a smartphone cpu and thus cut your computation time by a significant margin. Most likely below 10 seconds.  I just noticed he wants to run this in an App. My bad